# How can i display a blob image in a recursive array?

Tags: arrays, pdo, blob

I have a problem I need help with. Basically i am trying to query information from a database in to a news-ticker style type of array. I can get the text to show up but not the image, because it is in BLOB format. I tried to write the code in PDO but I am still a newb. I read alot of the articles on here about fetching blob images and displaying them. But most of the articles had instructions for deprecated code. Anyone who can be of assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here is my Source code as follows.

```
<style style="text/css">
.scroll-up {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.scroll-up p {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 padding-right: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);    
 transform:translateY(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
}
.clones_wrapper {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
 }
}
</style>

<div class="clones_wrapper">

<h2 align='center'>Clones</h2>

<table style = width:400px;><tr><th>Strain</th><th>Type</th><th>Rating</th><th>Price</th></tr></table>

<div class="scroll-up">
<p><?php


    echo "<table>";
    echo "<marquee  behavior='scroll', direction='up'></marquee>";

    class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td align='center' style='width:150px;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }

} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "clonemenudb";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=clonemenudb", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT strain, type, imagefile, price FROM clones_db"); 
    $stmt->execute();   


    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }


}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";

?>


</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved this answer today!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style style="text/css">
.scroll-up {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.scroll-up p {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 padding-right: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);    
 transform:translateY(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
}
.clones_wrapper {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: yellow;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
 }
}
</style>

<div class="clones_wrapper">

<h2 align='center'>Clones</h2>

<table  style = width:100%;><tr><th>Strain</th><th>Type</th><th>Rating</th><th>Price</th></tr></table>

<div class="scroll-up">
<p><table style = width:100%; cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">


                            <tbody>
                            <?php
                                require_once('db.php');
                                $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_image ORDER BY tbl_image_id ASC");
                                $result->execute();
                                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                                $id=$row['tbl_image_id'];
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:150px;"> <?php echo $row ['strain']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:100px;"> <?php echo $row ['strain_type']; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px; word-break:break-all; width:100px; line-height:50px">
                                    <?php if($row['rating'] != ""): ?>
                                    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['rating']; ?>" width="75px" height="18px">
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                    <img src="images/default.png" width="75x" height="18px">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:100px;"> <?php echo $row ['strain_price']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


</p>

    </div>
</div>
```